# Vault init through curl api using PGP keys failed

Tags: pgp, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to initialize hashicorp vault with api.

payload.json:

```
{
 "secret_shares": 2,
 "secret_threshold": 2,
 "pgp_keys": [
            "sample_pub_1.asc",
            "sample_pub_2.asc"
        ]
}
```

When I execute below command:

```
curl     --request PUT     --data @payload.json     http://localhost:8200/v1/sys/init
```

Getting below error:

> {"errors":["invalid seal configuration: error decoding given PGP key:> illegal base64 data at input byte 6"]}

But If I initialize Vault with command line everything works fine:

```
vault operator init -key-shares=2 -key-threshold=2 -pgp-keys="sample_pub_1.asc, sample_pub_2.asc"
```

Below is the output:

> Unseal Key 1: 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
>
> Unseal Key 2: 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
>
> Initial Root Token: aa3cccce-5ac8-4aef-7d50-6fab16e89ee4

Comment: Are keys base64-encoded?

Comment: Yes I exported using below command:  gpg -a --export ADXX0SS9B4 > sample_pub_1.asc

Answer (score 0):

You might not have base64-encoded your pgp_keys; according to the [official Vault documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/system/init.html#pgp_keys) when using curl init:

> The keys must be base64-encoded from their original binary representation

Comment: Yes I exported using below command: gpg -a --export ADXX0SS9B4 > sample_pub_1.asc

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the original binary output in Base64.

On my Mac:

```
gpg2 --export sample@stackoverflow.com | base64 -b 0
```

Or on Linux:

```
gpg2 --export sample@stackoverflow.com | base64 -w 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference of use between the vault command and HTTP API.

While the command can read a file from disk and allows the file name as a parameter as your example shows correctly:

```
vault operator init -key-shares=2 -key-threshold=2 -pgp-keys="sample_pub_1.asc, sample_pub_2.asc"
```

The HTTP API needs the base64 key in this field instead the file name.

```
{  "secret_shares": 2,  "secret_threshold": 2,  "pgp_keys": [
        "mQGNBF/ALSkBDADoIAuvrTNbvkuZZTl28Pwh7i0aa.......",
        "mQGNBF/ALSkBDADoIAuvrTNbvkuZZTl28Pwh7i0aa......."
    ]
```

}

That's why the error indicates the bad byte in the position number 6 because is trying to decode the string "sample_pub_1.asc" as a base64 valid value.

best regards